# What powershell command can change the TextInfo.ListSeparator?

Tags: powershell

I am loading data into ERP software which requires the end user to change their default ListSeparator from , to |

Documentation for the software states that the user should open "Region and Language" settings and select the "Additional Settings..." button to change it, however I am trying to avoid users having to make this change.

I would like to automate the process to change the listSeparator for the duration of this process but also automatically change it back and not leave it as |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give credit where credit is due, please see original source of this function located at:
https://gist.github.com/abombss/1129655

```
function toggle-list-sep
{
  $path = "hkcu:\Control Panel\International"
  $key = "sList"

  $cur_sep = (Get-ItemProperty -path $path -name $key).$key

  if ($args.Length -gt 0) { $value = $args[0] }
  elseif ($cur_sep -eq ",") { $value = "|" } 
  else { $value = "," }

  Set-ItemProperty -path $path -name $key -Value $value -type string
  $new_sep = (Get-ItemProperty -path $path -name $key).$key

  Write-Output "Changed $path.$key from '$cur_sep' to '$new_sep'"
}
```

From that you should be able to either just run the function before and after the application or extrapolate what you need to make the exact script that you want.